# How to select specific text to scrape

Tags: kotlin, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape the following HTML, I want just to get the `Some Header` part and not the `additional info`.

```
<li class="media"> 
     <div class="media-body"> 
      <a href="url.html"> <h4> Some Header <span class="label label-info"> additional Info </span> </h4> </a> Address info
      <br> 
     </div> </li>`
```

I'm trying the following:

```
   val li: Elements = ul.select("li") 
    val list: Elements = li.select("a") 
    val headers: Elements = list.select("h4")
```

`

and then when I try to get the inner text via, `headers.text()` I'm getting both `Some Header` and `additional Info`

How can I only scrape the `Some Header` part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost near to the solution .You are probably looking for calling [ownText](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText()):

```
String s = "<li class=\"media\"> \n" +
        "     <div class=\"media-body\"> \n" +
        "      <a href=\"url.html\"> <h4> Some Header <span class=\"label label-info\"> additional Info </span> </h4> </a> Address info\n" +
        "      <br> \n" +
        "     </div> </li>";

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(s);
        Elements element = document.select("li");

        Elements elements = element.select("a");
        System.out.println(elements.select("h4").first().ownText()); ;
```

Output:

```
Some Header
```